# Shell script Variable Structure

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards

How can I create a variable with a file name format like :

FileName pattern: SnapshotIR__somenumber.csv

I tried something like :

```
TODAY=$(date +"%m%d%Y")    
SNAPSHOT = $(SnapshotIR$TODAY*.csv)
```

I get error like :

```
test.sh: line 2: SnapshotIR02122013_2239.csv: command not found
test.sh: line 2: SNAPSHOT: command not found
```

so, when I want to use with if

```
if [ -f SnapshotIR$TODAY*.csv]  -> works 
if [ -f ${SNAPSHOT} ]           -> does not work (I get the above error)
```

Comment: To help you with more than how to assign variables you might want to include your whole script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `$()` shell will execute the content inside braces as command. 
You're not allowed to use spaces before/after `=` symbol.

So your command will be as

```
SNAPSHOT=SnapshotIR$TODAY*.csv
```

or

```
SNAPSHOT=SnapshotIR${TODAY}*.csv
```

ps. If you need to make some operations with this files in next step, it's better to use `for` cycle like

```
for file in SnapshotIR${TODAY}*.csv ; do smth ; done
```

cause in case you have several files matching your pattern, `[ -f ${SNAPSHOT} ]` contruction will return an error like:

```
[ -f f* ] && echo ok
-bash: [: filename: binary operator expected
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> SNAPSHOT = $(SnapshotIR$TODAY*.csv)
> ```

You can't have a space in assignments. Furthermore, `$(…)` is a [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution): this line attempts to execute `SnapshotIR02122013_2239.csv` as a program.

In bash, ksh or zsh, set `SNAPSHOT` to be an array containing the list of matching file names.

```
SNAPSHOT=("SnapshotIR$TODAY"*.csv)
```

If there is no matching file, the pattern is left unexpanded. In bash or zsh, set the `nullglob` option to get an empty array instead. In ksh, put `~(N)` at the beginning of the pattern (i.e. `SNAPSHOT=(~(N)"SnapshotIR$TODAY"*.csv)`). You can then test if there were any matching files by testing the length of the array.

```
shopt -s nullglob
SNAPSHOT=("SnapshotIR$TODAY"*.csv)
if [ ${#SNAPSHOT} -eq 0 ]; then
  echo 1>&2 "No snapshot file for $TODAY"
  exit 2
elif [ ${#SNAPSHOT} -gt 1 ]; then
  echo 1>&2 "Multiple snapshot files for $TODAY, I don't know which one to pick"
  exit 2
fi
echo "The snapshot file is ${SNAPSHOT[0]}"
```

In shells without arrays, you can use a function that receives the list of matches and counts them. If there is no match, the function receives the pattern unexpanded.

```
set_snapshot () {
  if [ $# -gt 1 ]; then
    echo 1>&2 "Multiple snapshot files for $TODAY, I don't know which one to pick"
    exit 2
  elif [ -e "$1" ]; then
     SNAPSHOT=$1
  else
    echo 1>&2 "No snapshot file for $TODAY"
    exit 2
  fi
}
set_snapshot "SnapshotIR$TODAY"*.csv
echo "The snapshot file is $SNAPSHOT"
```

(Note that using `[ -e "$1" ]` to test whether the pattern was left unexpanded fails in pathological cases such as `[0-9]` when there is no file whose name is a single digit but there is a file with the 5-character name `[0-9]`. This can't happen with only `*` or `?` metacharacters since they match themselves.)

The following approach works to some extent:

```
SNAPSHOT=SnapshotIR$TODAY"*.csv
if [ -e $SNAPSHOT ]; then …
```

Since the expansion `$SNAPSHOT` is left unquoted, it is treated as a whitespace-separated list of wildcard patterns, which is ok here. However, if there is more than one matching file, the matches will be seen as separate arguments by the `[` command, and that will cause a syntax error. (With specially-crafted file names, it could even cause a wrong result.) So I don't recommend this approach, it's too brittle.

Comment: Thanks for showing the correct methods. First example should use `${#snapshot[@]}`, ideally `(( ! ${#snapshot[@]} ))`, though in this specific case testing the 0th element will give the illusion of working anyway.

Comment: @ormaaj Right. In ksh and bash, `${#foo}` is the length of the first element of the array. When dealing with an array of file names, which can't be empty, `${#foo}` is 0 only if the array is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Do *not* use spaces around `=` when [assigning variables](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varassignment.html).

Also, I do not think you want to enclose what `SNAPSHOT` is assigned to in `$( )` as that tries to execute it as a command.

On a side note, consider [to lowercase your variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/673940/789593).

So what you want may be

```
today=$(date +"%m%d%Y")    
snapshot=SnapshotIR$today

if [ -f ${snapshot}*.csv ]
```

Comment: Beware that if more than one file matches `${snapshot}*.csv`, all hell will break loose.